# How to order by many values in Elasticsearch terms aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

How do you order ES terms aggregations by multiple values?

At the moment i do:

```
aggs : {
    aggName : {
        terms : {
            field : "foo",
            order : { "subAgg.avg" : "desc" }
        }
    },
    aggs : {
        subAgg : {
            stats : {
                field : "bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The API says you can do:

```
order : [ { "subAgg.avg" : "desc" }, { "subAgg.count" : "desc" } ]
```

But this does not work, ES throws an error:

```
Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [aggName]: [order].
```

I found something like this in other posts:

```
order : { "subAgg.avg" : "desc", "subAgg.count" : "desc" }
```

No error, but not sorted correctly.

My question is, how to correctly sort by many values?
I have ES 1.4.4 installed.

thx

EDITED:
Mapping

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "mymapping" : {
      "properties" : {
        "foo" : {
          "type" : "short"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
    query : { 
        match_all : {} 
    },
    aggs : {
        aggName : {
            terms : {
                field : "foo",
                order : [ { "subAgg.avg" : "desc" }, { "subAgg.count" : "desc" } ]
            },
            aggs : {
                subAgg : {
                    stats : {
                        field : "foo"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: by this document (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) it looks that your syntax is correct. give us the the mapping of your document

Comment: added mapping and full query, without the order clause, query runs error free, but once order is of type array it gives: SearchParseException[[mymapping][1]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [aggName]: [order].]]

Comment: Using ES 1.5.0, I'm doing exactly what you show above except that I'm ordering by two different sub-aggregations.  Other than that, essentially the same thing and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
"order" : [ { "rock>playback_stats.avg" : "desc" }, { "_count" : "desc" } ]
```

From: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "countries" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "artist.country",
            "order" : [ { "rock>playback_stats.avg" : "desc" }, { "_count" : "desc" } ]
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "rock" : {
                "filter" : { "term" : { "genre" : "rock" }},
                "aggs" : {
                    "playback_stats" : { "stats" : { "field" : "play_count" }}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```